# Google App Engine Embedded entity seems to vanish from cache

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I use java memcache api to store not persistent data associated with the user. Every user has associated memcache entity storing some properties, some of the properties are embedded entities. After a while they dissappear while other properties ( String, Integer, Boolean ) persist. Is it intended to be so or I am missing something in my code? Can I rely on entitites stored in cache at least for an hour or something like this? I see this behaviour when debugging on local machine with google plugin. My code is like this:

```
class UserData {
    public Entity getEntity() {
        Entity ret = new Entity( "User", key );
        ret.setProperty( "property1", _integerval );
        ret.setProperty( "property2", _stringval );
        ret.setProperty( "property3", _complex.getEmbEntity() );
        return ret;
    }

    public static UserData fromEntity( Entity ent ) {
        UserData ret = new UserData();
        ret._integerval = (Integer)ent.getProperty("property1");
        ret._stringval = (String)ent.getProperty("property2");
        ret._complex.fromEmbEntity( (EmbeddedEntity)ent.getProperty("property3") );
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember google's implementation will not guarantee any entity will hang around. Anything can be evicted at any point. From the docs:

> However, when considering whether to store a value solely in the
>   memcache and not backed by other persistent storage, be sure that your
>   application behaves acceptably when the value is suddenly not
>   available. Values can expire from the memcache at any time, and may be
>   expired prior to the expiration deadline set for the value.

Comment: Agreed, treat memcache like a cache, not reliable storage.